# Error al conectarme al servidor de Hue. usando docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, hive

estoy tratando de utilizar el servidor de Hue, por medio de docker-compose, a la hora de iniciar la sesion me da error y no puedo trabajar dentro de la plataforma.

Abajo les dejo una imagen del error.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tambien viendo en la terminal tengo este ERROR:

ERROR Not using HDFS upload handler: HTTPConnectionPool(host=‘namenode’, port=50070): Max retries exceeded with url: /webhdfs/v1/?op=GETFILESTATUS&user.name=hue&doas=instructor (Caused by NewConnectionError(‘<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7ff7540d7210>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known’,))

Gracias, espero que alguien pueda ayudarme.